# Header `execution` and `std::reduce` not found

Tags: c++, header, c++17

I am trying to get this snippet to compile

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <execution>

double result = std::reduce(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end());
```

I tried these compilers:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)

clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)

g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```

All three give me `'execution' file not found`

respectively `error: no member named 'reduce' in namespace 'std'
    auto result = std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end());`

for this snippet

```
#include<numeric>
#include<vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<double> v(10, 1);

    auto result = std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end());
    return 0;
}
```

I guess my compilers are too old? But [on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) it does not say which compiler version is requiered minimum and also I do not see any newer versions for clang or gcc in the repo.

Comment: If you check the [libc++ status page](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html), you'll see most (none?) of the parallel execution stuff has been implemented yet.

Comment: Ah ok, did not say so on cppreference.

Comment: "...on cppreference it does not say which compiler version..." - cppreference rarely mentions specific compiler toolchains. Rather, it denotes *language* and standard library requirements. This case is no different. The "(since C++17)" tells you what whatever toolchain you're using must support.

Comment: Two years later (Apr-2019) still no support in libc++, nor in libstdc++. The beast has it, what a shame.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`std::reduce` and `std::execution::par` are available since C++17.

For most of the compilers C++17 isn't fully implemented yet. You can try using clang with flag `-std=c++1z`.

Comment: Beware. You still might get an error with clang++ if that uses the system libstdc++ and not libc++.

Comment: @rwst also `-std=c++17` is fine

Answer (score 5):

I upgraded my GCC to version 10 and it compiled fine the `std::execution::par` with its include `<execution>` (which was failing to locate with gcc version 7.5.0). I followed to the instructions in this link: https://tuxamito.com/wiki/index.php/Installing_newer_GCC_versions_in_Ubuntu