# Problem with using header of <execution> in c++

Tags: c++, header, execution, seq, par

I have gcc 10.2.0 on windows 10. so,  is implemented in this latest version of gcc.
The problem is when I copy the example code from the following link :https://docs.w3cub.com/cpp/algorithm/reduce, it says: std::execution has not been declared. Any idea?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <execution>
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v(10'000'007, 0.5);
 
    {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        double result = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0);
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms = t2 - t1;
        std::cout << std::fixed << "std::accumulate result " << result
                  << " took " << ms.count() << " ms\n";
    }
 
    {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        double result = std::reduce(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end());
        auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> ms = t2 - t1;
        std::cout << "std::reduce result "
                  << result << " took " << ms.count() << " ms\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you enable the C++17 flag?

Comment: In addition, please show your compilation command.

Comment: [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/751eGq)

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689444/header-execution-and-stdreduce-not-found

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks for this answer!It worked just by enabling c++ 17 flag on my settings of eclipse IDE. How should I accept the answer?

Comment: By enabling c++ 17 flag, this code compiled  fine. But, a surprising result is that using std::reduce takes more time than using std::accumulate. I do not know why I am getting this weird result:std::accumulate result 5000003.500000 took 93.749400 ms
std::reduce result 5000003.500000 took 153.627900 ms

Comment: @M.A Thanks for your reply! now, the weird result is that std::reduce shows more execution time than std::accumulate. Do you have any idea why I am getting this unexpected result?

Comment: @Movahedi-24 sure, multi-threading does not guarantee improved performance. I've not read through the standard implementation for parallel algos, but there is a cost associated with both starting and destroying threads/thread pools. Also, in the parallel case, you end up doing more work, as you have to chunk up the data in subsections for each thread to work on, then accumulate at the end. You are limited by the slowest thread. So synchronisation and resource time-sharing also need to be factored in. If you were doing more work within each thread, you may start to see greater benefit.

Comment: @M.A Many thanks for the explanation! I am new to c++ so there are terms that I have to first look up to understand your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many compilers default to older C++ modes for backwards compatability. Enable C++17 in the settings to use newer features.